# How to trigger change in html select when using ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React app with hooks.

```
const [regions, setRegions] = useState([]);
const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);
const regionRef = useRef(null);
const cityRef = useRef(null);

const citiesAndRegions = [
    {
        _id: 123, name: 'California', cities: [{id: 'abc', name: 'LA'},{id: 'efg', name: 'Hollywood'}]
    },
    {
        ,_id: 456, name: 'Florida', cities: [{id: 'hji', name: 'Miami'}]
    }
];

const regionChanged = async (id) => {
    const found = citiesAndRegions.find(el => el._id === id);
    setCities(found.cities);
}

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRegions = async () => {
        const region_result = [{_id: 123, name: 'California',_id: 456, name: 'Florida'}];
        region_result.forEach(el => {
            el.value = el._id;
            el.label = el.name;
        });
        setRegions(region_result);
    }
    const setDefaultValues = async () => {
        const user = {name: 'Jack', region: 123, city: 'abc'};
        await fetchRegions();
        regionRef.current.value = user.region;
        await regionChanged(user.region);
        cityRef.current.value = user.city;
    }
    setDefaultValues().catch(console.error);
}, []);

return(
    <select ref={regionRef} onChange={e => regionChanged(e.target.value)}>
        {
            regions.map((opt, index) =>
                <option key={index} value={opt.value}>{opt.label}</option>
            )
        }
    </select>
    <select ref={cityRef}>
        {
            cities.map((opt, index) =>
                <option key={index} value={opt.id}>{opt.name}</option>
            )
        }
    </select>
);
```

So in function useEffect I fetch first data about the user. Then all the regions. Then I set the reference for the region. After that, I trigger the change od the regions which implies fetching the cities. And at the end I set the current value for the city reference.

What happens is that all the regions are in the select box. And region "California" is selected. Moreover, in the city-select I see all the cities for the California region. However, the city with id "abc" (which is "LA") is not getting selected.
How do I trigger this change?

Comment: Instead of using references to set the value of the selects you could try `useState`

Comment: Well I know, but this would be plan b.